# What is the best way to integrate DynamoDB stream with CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudsearch, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'd like to achieve near real time search for a document service, and here is my idea:

1. I plan to use DynamoDB as my primary document store;
2. and then whenever a new document update happens, an event in DynamoDB stream is created;
3. I'd like to ask CloudSearch to pick up the events in the stream and update the index in CloudSearch

My question is how to integrate DynamoDB stream with CloudSearch. I feel I could use Lambda function in between (i.e., trigger a lambda function, which execute a write/update the index operation, to process an event in the stream). I would work, but I just feel it may be an expensive way to achieve my goal (because lambda cost $$).

Does Amazon provide any hook that directly integrate DynamoDB stream with CloudSearch? I am wondering this approach because of the following illustration figure (it clearly implied that CloudSearch and Lambda are different integration point).[image]

Comment: Did you estimate how much you'd actually be spending? There's some discussion of cost on the answer in my previous comment and I think you'd be surprised how little it is. Do the math, weigh the cost vs the alternative, and don't "just feel like it may be expensive"

Comment: @alexroussos, it would still be great to see a back-of-envolope calculation with a concrete number. "1M free lambda call" sounds a lot, but if we include things like API-Gateway triggered lambda, that quota quickly goes away.